# Image inside the Div element not showing

Tags: html, css

```
div {position: relative;}


#wrapper { 

background: url('ocean.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position:  center;
background-size: 100% auto;

}

<body>

<div id="wrapper">
 </div>
```

I am trying alternate ways to present the background image of ocean.png in different elements.  Right now I am putting into a div and it isn't showing.   Earlier, I put into the body which shows and the image able to stretch fullsize when first stretched horizontally and then vertically on the browser but when I stretch vertically first then background image in body is not stretching full screen, white space on top and bottom.

I am experimenting on a div now but it didn't show up at all.

Comment: Have you tried actually adding a width and heigth to it? Or adding content?

Comment: Have you tried ANY debug tools (chrome's, or firebug, or whatever) to see if the div is actually there or what those "white spaces on top and bottom" are?

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the width for the wrapper. width:100% and height:100%

Answer (score 1):

Need to set the width and height of the wrapper div, also if the image is not in the same directory as the CSS the reference is wrong.  if you have images in a /images directory you should call them as `url(/images/myimage.png)`

Answer (score 1):

Set the `width` and `height` of the wrapper as others have said and join those css styles in one declaration and you can get rid of all other styles once you set the dimensions of the container.

`background: url(ocean.png) center no-repeat`